# jQuery Multi-Select Listbox where 'None' Option Deselects All Others

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q0o11c5e/17/

I have a Multi-Select Listbox with 'None' with the following requirements:

1. Selecting 'None' included **anywhere** in the selection => only 'None'
   is selected (anything else is turned off)
2. Deselecting any other item
       with Ctrl+click, if nothing else is selected, will automatically
       select 'None'.

This is implemented with jQuery's Change function. My issues:

1) First of all, for #2 (Full Ctrl+click deselection): the flow doesn't come into the `$( "#listbox" ).change(function()` at all. You can see that because if you select '**A**' and then deselect it with Ctrl+click, the Alert at the top of the function isn't displayed.

2) For #1, if the selection includes 'None' (value '') anywhere, I create a blank array, push '' onto it, and set the Listbox Val to it (and break immediately), but that doesn't work.

```
$( "#listbox" ).change(function() {   

   alert('SelArray: ' + $('#listbox').val() +  '   Length: ' + $('#listbox').val().length);

   // If no selection, automatically select 'None'
   if ($('#listbox').val().length == 0) {
        alert('Nothing selected');
   }
   else
   {
     // If new selection includes empty ('None'), deselect any other active selections
     $.each($('#listbox').val(), function (index, value) {
        if (value == '') {
          alert('None selected, clearing anything else..');
          var noneOnly = {};
          noneOnly.push('');
          $('#listbox').val(noneOnly);
          return false;
        }
     });

   }


});
```

Comment: Just a minor point, and irrelevant to your problem, but to me selecting "all" would imply all options should be selected, I'd be confused if selecting "all" visually selected "none." More so if *deselecting* all options then automatically selected "all," it feels like the UI you describe is counter intuitive.

Comment: True, I'll rename it now.

Comment: Looks like `noneOnly` in your deselecting code is actually an object: `{}`. If you change that to `[]`, the deselecting should work better.

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot Andrew Myers, how about the deselection of a single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the intention correctly, something like the below?

```
$( "#listbox" ).change(function() {   
   var arr=  $(this).val();
   if (arr == null || arr.length === 0 || (arr.length > 1 && arr[0] === ''))
        $(this).val(['']);
});
```

This simply sets the selection whenever no value is selected or when multiple values are selected including 'none'

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0o11c5e/21/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#listbox").on("input change", function() {
    if($(this).find("option[value='']:selected").length!=0 || $(this).find("option:selected").length==0) {
    $(this).find("option").attr("selected", false);
    $(this).find("option[value='']").attr("selected", true);
    return false;
  }
});
```

hi, check my above piece of code, this is my try https://jsfiddle.net/q0o11c5e/22/

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This is solved now, final fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q0o11c5e/23/

JS code:

```
$( "#listbox" ).change(function() {   

   var arr=  $(this).val();
   if (arr == null || arr.length === 0 || (arr.length > 1 && arr[0] === '')) {
        $(this).val(['']);
   }   
   else
   {
     // If new selection includes empty ('None'), deselect any other active selections
     $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        if (value == '') {
          var noneOnly = [];
          noneOnly.push('');
          $('#listbox').val(noneOnly);
          return false;
        }
     });

   }


});
```